# Get only one element in left join sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I get the first row of a custom order in SQLITE ?

I want to left join table revue with table article in such a way that for each revue, article (joined at id_revue) with the highest lettre (in order) is selected. When there are more than one article with same lettre than min(etat) decides the selection as per value "Validate" = 1, "Read" = 2, "Write" = 3

**table Revue**

```
id  nom
1   nom 1
2   nom 2
```

**Table Article**

```
id  lettre  etat    id_revue
1   A       write       1
2   B       read        1
3   B       validate    1
4   A       write       2
5   B       write       2
6   C       validate    2
7   B       write       1
8   C       write       1
9   C       write       2
```

I use the following request

```
Select * from revue as t1 
left join (
select * from article
    group by id_revue
    order by lettre,
    case 
        when etat = "write" then 3
        when etat = "read" then 2
        when etat = "validate" then 1
    end
) as t2 on t2.id_revue = t1.id
```

I obtain this result but the order by case doesn't works:

```
1   nom 1   8   C   write   1    
2   nom 2   9   C   write   2
```

I want to get the biggest letter for each article and if there identical letter I want the order "Validate, Read an write.

```
1   nom 1   8   C   write     1    
2   nom 2   6   C   validate  2
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by:  "How can I get the first row of a custom order in SQLITE ?"  Nothing in your code is called "order" and there are no dates.

Comment: That query does not produce the results you say it does, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Using a modern version of sqlite (3.25 or newer):

```
WITH cte AS
  (SELECT a.id_revue, r.nom, a.id AS id_article, a.lettre, a.etat
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY r.id
                             ORDER BY a.lettre DESC
                                    , CASE a.etat
                                       WHEN 'validate' THEN 1
                                       WHEN 'read' THEN 2
                                       WHEN 'write' THEN 3
                                      END DESC) AS rn
   FROM revue AS r 
   JOIN article AS a ON r.id = a.id_revue)
SELECT id_revue, nom, id_article, lettre, etat
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id_revue;
```

```
id_revue    nom         id_article  lettre      etat      
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           nom 1       8           C           write     
2           nom 2       9           C           write
```

---

You do need to clarify more how you want the `etat` column sorted, as *the biggest value of them as following sorted ("Validate", "Read", "Write")* gives your and the above results, but your expected results for the `id_revue` of 2 keep the article id of 9 but has an etat value of `'validate'`, which isn't even in a row in your test data - there's an article id of 6 with that value for `etat` that would get returned if you're looking for the *first* row with that sort order, not the biggest/last, though. To get that, remove the appropriate `DESC` from the above query:

```
id_revue    nom         id_article  lettre      etat      
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           nom 1       8           C           write     
2           nom 2       6           C           validate
```

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understood from your question, following query is what you are after

```
Select a.id_revue, t1.nom, a.id article_id, a.lettre, a.etat 
from revue as t1 
left join (
   select fa.id, wa.lettre, fa.etat, wa.id_revue
   from article fa
   join ( 
       select a1.lettre, a1.id_revue, 
            min(case 
                when etat = 'write' then 3
                when etat = 'read' then 2
                when etat = 'validate' then 1
                end) etat_ord
        from article a1
        join (
            select max(lettre) lettre, id_revue from article 
            group by id_revue
        ) a2 on a2.lettre = a1.lettre and a1.id_revue = a2.id_revue
        group by a1.lettre, a1.id_revue
    )wa on fa.lettre = wa.lettre and fa.id_revue = wa.id_revue and fa.etat =
    case wa.etat_ord when 3 then 'write' when 2 then 'read' else 'validate' end
)a on t1.id = a.id_revue
;
```

Note: DB with window functions' support could have shorter query for same result, SQLITE doesn't support window functions.

Comment: Modern versions of sqlite have window functions, btw.

Comment: @Shawn - Thanks for passing this information, just downloaded the latest and tested successfully. +1 for this..